# UIScrollView limited scrollable area

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiscrollview, area, scrollable

I have a UIScrollView which contains a timelime. Sometimes I may only want to let the user see say one third of the view and therefore I would like it to only show this part of the scrollview but still have this nice "bouncing" effect in both ends of the view to "preview" what is outside the scrollable area.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limiting the scrollable area in UIScrollView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973461/limiting-the-scrollable-area-in-uiscrollview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should specify the size of the UIScrollView to end where you want your user to scroll to but leave the size of the inner view (subview) of the UIScrollView.

Comment: Oh yes. Now I realize that this might have been a stupid question.  Making the UIScrollView wider than the `contentSize` does the trick. If you want to set where the UIScrollView should start from you can use the `contentInset` of the scrollview. Thank you very much!