# UIScrollView "Touch" Issue

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I am rather stumped on a `UIScrollView` issue. 
- I am appending a series of `UIImageViews` to a `UIScrollView` and that works fine and the "contentsize" is updating appropriately.
- `UIScrollView` is next inside of `UIView` (all other interactive elements work fine) 
- The view only scrolls horizontally
- The scrollView frame is 300 x 40 (width / height).
- System notes: I am producing this for iOS 5+

MY PROBLEM: I can only scroll this view by touching on the far left of the scrollview. The whole view should respond to touches and does not!!! it just looks like the left 25-30% is responding to the touch and allowing me to scroll. The view IS NOT covered by any other view / component that may hinder interactivity.

All help would save some stress 
-AJ

Comment: i think you need to enable the user interaction of imageView, by default that is no.

Comment: I'm not worried about the UiImageViews added to the scrollView being interactive (enabled)... those do not need to.  It's the scrollView that is having issues - this bug is driving me crazy :-|  But fro peace of mind, I did try this earlier and it had no affect.

Comment: Is this happens from starting or this happens after you done for the first time.

Comment: happens every time... again, the scrollView "is" scrolling but I can only start my "touch" on the far left of the scrollView

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the iteration with the UIScrollView is covered up by the UIImageViews.  Try changing some properties.

Comment: Yeah, thats not it... I created a loop to add borders to all subviews in the UIView containing the scrollView and nothing is covering the scrollView to "block" interactivity.  The UIImageViews I am adding are being added to the scrollView properly, but I can't "touch" anywhere in the scrollView to "scroll" - just on the far left... looks like about for 0 - 75 pixels or so before the interactivity "touch getting "blocked".  Very strange...

Comment: Have you tried setting the content size?  
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(px width, px height)];

Comment: Yes, no issues with the contentsize... that is setting properly.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3973461/1483002) << this seems like its kind of what you are dealing with. Might help.

Comment: Yeah, I am going to just have to close this... I have eliminated everything on the view but the scrollView to see if something may just be "blocking" the view... and I JUST can't see what the issue here is.