# Setting the scrollable area UISCrollView

Tags: uiscrollview

I tryed to use answer it this quiestion [Limiting the scrollable area in UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973461/limiting-the-scrollable-area-in-uiscrollview) however i didnt succeed in my problem.

I have a UIScrollView that contains 3 UIView one after another. When I press on the UIView I add a UITableView under UIView i pressed. At this moment I need to limit scrolling area, so I could scroll only this TableView and UIView.At another press on UIView I hide the UITableView and I can scroll further in horizontal direction. My question is - how its possible to implement scrolling only in that area I described? Only thing I know is I have to change contentSize of my UISCrollView, but when I do it I get to the beginning of UIScrollView.